# Showing google map in android webview

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I've created an app where a Google map is showed in a webview. This works fine, except one thing: I can't zoom in or zoom out with my fingers on my android device, i can only use the zoom buttons in Google Maps to zoom. Is there a possibility to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

we have simple solution for that, jst open map of Google in webview and use Google api to display your location.

i hope you got it.